# Losing data changed by javascript during postback

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I have this asp.net control:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" ReadOnly="true" />
```

and I want to be it readonly, usually I do it with `ReadOnly="trye"` or with `Enable="false"`

if I change the value of this control through javascript in the client side, The changed value will not be propagated via postback in the serverside...whatever I do with javascript will not work, unless I remove the `readonly="true"` and `enable="false"`.

How can I make it readonly so that when I change the value with javascript the value will be propogated via postback?

Answer (score 0):

The Solution to **"Losing data changed by javascript during postback"**
is best described by this article 
[ViewState and Readonly Property of Textbox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33649/ViewState-and-Readonly-Property-of-Textbox)

for example let's say we have this asp.net control:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" EnableViewState= "false" ReadOnly="true" />
```

if you change the value of this control through javascript in the client side the changed value will not be propagated via postback in the serverside...whatever you do with javascript unless you remove `readonly="true"`. Now there is a solution to this problem as described in the article above.

Simply put this in the PageLoad event

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    txtName.Attribute.Add("readonly","readonly");
```

and you're done. Just don't forget to remove `ReadOnly="true"` or `Enable="false"` if your intent was to disable the control from editing just use the snippet above. Don't forget to remove `Enable="false"` if you put it on.